# ASP.NET Core Stateful service

Tags: asp.net-core, stateful

We are looking to build stateful service with ASP.NET Core. We need to have multiple instances of the same service with shared state (perhaps stored in database)

Are there any frameworks available apart of Service Fabric to build stateful services?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a shared session with the help of Redis IDistributedCache. You can find more info from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-session-state